# Sqlite Insert Two Table - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to add two tables at the same time in Android. Im trying like 2 hours to do it but im lost now. I have 2 tables as i said. They are Body and Person tables. Person table works fine but Body doesnt. Body has a foreign key which points Person's PK.

This is where im lost.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "healthMonitor.db";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Person";
private static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "Body";
// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String BODY_KEY_ID = "bId";
private static final String FOREIGN_KEY_ID = "personId";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_ARM = "arm";
private static final String KEY_BRAIN = "brain";
private static final String KEY_EYE = "eye";
private static final String KEY_HEART = "heart";
private static final String KEY_LEG = "leg";
private static final String KEY_SURNAME = "surname";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
private static final String KEY_EYECOLOR = "eyeColor";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private String createFirstTable(){
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_SURNAME + " TEXT, "+
            KEY_AGE + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_EYECOLOR + " TEXT);";

    return query;
}

private String createSecondTable(){
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (" +
            BODY_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_ARM + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_BRAIN + " INTEGER, "+
            KEY_EYE + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_HEART + " INTEGER, "+
            KEY_LEG +" INTEGER, " +
            FOREIGN_KEY_ID + " INTEGER, "+
            FOREIGN_KEY_ID + " FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES "+TABLE_NAME+ "("+KEY_ID+");";

    return query;
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(createFirstTable());
    db.execSQL(createSecondTable());
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "," + TABLE_NAME2);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

boolean addContact(MainActivity.Person person) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, person.getName()); // Person Name
    values.put(KEY_SURNAME, person.getSurname()); // Person Surname
    values.put(KEY_AGE, person.getAge()); // Person Age
    values.put(KEY_EYECOLOR, person.getEyeColor()); // Person Surname

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    //db.close(); // Closing database connection
    return true;
}

boolean addBody() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ARM, 5); // Person Name
    values.put(KEY_BRAIN, 4); // Person Surname
    values.put(KEY_EYE, 3); // Person Age
    values.put(KEY_HEART, 2); // Person Surname
    values.put(KEY_LEG, 1); // Person Age
    values.put(FOREIGN_KEY_ID, 1); // Person Surname

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, values);
    //db.close(); // Closing database connection
    return true;
}
```

Please check onCreate() function. Im really lost. Thanks

> "FOREIGN KEY ("+ FOREIGN_KEY_ID + ") REFERENCES "+TABLE_NAME+
> "("+KEY_ID+");"

And

> FOREIGN_KEY_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES "+TABLE_NAME+ "("+KEY_ID+");";

This one is not working either

## CORRECT ONE

**FOREIGN_KEY_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES "+TABLE_NAME+ "("+KEY_ID+"));";**

Comment: Dump your all SQL command as string, and you'll understand where's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the close parenthesis in your 2nd query

your code:`FOREIGN_KEY_ID + " FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES "+TABLE_NAME+ "("+KEY_ID+");";`

updated: `FOREIGN_KEY_ID + " FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES "+TABLE_NAME+ "("+KEY_ID+"));";`

Comment: Yeah, as i said yesterday, this solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Just always check your query, it is very sensitive. Goodluck